# Помогите найти ошибку в коде определения последнего максимума

Tags: python

Мне необходимо найти наибольшее значение в списке и индекс последнего элемента, который имеет данное значение за один проход по списку, не модифицируя этот список и не используя дополнительного списка. На выходе должно быть два значения.

При тестировании не при всех комбинациях работает правильно.

Вот мой код:

```
l = list(map(int, input().split()))
n = 0
for x in range(0, len(l) + 1):
    if x > l[-n]:
        n += 1
print(l[-n], n)
```

Comment: А на каком примере у вас  не сработало?

Answer (score 0):

```
l = list(map(int, input().split()))
Maximum = (Minimum_possible_value)
MaximumIndex = -1
for x in range(len(l)):
  if (l[x] >= Maximum):
    Maximum = l[x]
    MaximumIndex = x
print(Maximum, MaximumIndex)
```

Comment: при тестировании выводит ошибку: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Корвин/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/scratches/test1.py", line 2, in <module>
    Maxim = (Minimum_possible_value)
NameError: name 'Minimum_possible_value' is not defined

Comment: Вы заменили Minimum_possible_value на минимально возможное значение? Кажется, нет.

Comment: Точно. 
Maximum = max(l) и всё работает. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Maximum = l[0] или Maximum = минус_бесконечность или типо того, почему max(I)?)
Я не очень понимаю, что вы имели ввиду.

Comment: l = list(map(int, input().split()))
Maxim = max(l)
MaximumIndex = -1
for x in range(len(l)):
    if (l[x] >= Maxim):
        Maximum = l[x]
        MaximumIndex = x
print(Maxim, MaximumIndex)

Такой код выводит значение последнего максимума из вводимого списка.

max(l) достанет со списка максимальное число

Comment: Ну технически это два пробега на самом деле)
Вы просили один
а в последнем предложенном вами только что решении один пробег выполняет функция max(l)

Comment: Только изучаю Python 3 из-за рабочей необходимости и часто игнорирую некоторые условия задач получая результат другим способом. Сейчас попробую за один проход..

Comment: Попробуйте искать простым алгоритмом поиска максимума, который я описал

Answer (score 0):

```
l = list(map(int, input().split()))
n,m=0,0
for i in range(len(l)):
    if l[i]>n:
        n=l[i]
        m=i
print(n,m)
```